# Buying a pay as you go metro card in Tromsø, Norway

Tags: norway

So I collect metro smart cards and I was trying to get the one for Tromso, Norway, but it is unclear to me as to how.

https://fylkestrafikk.no/menu/tickets-and-fares/how-to-buy-a-ticket-on-buses-and-express-boats/travelcard/ says you can buy a pay as you go card from "customer service centres", "sales centres", "ticket vending machines", etc.

My question is..  where are these sales centers or customer service centers located? Like do 7-11s count as sales centers?

The ticket vending machines let you reload Troms cards but it doesn't let you buy new ones. At least the ones that look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching for *Service Center* on that same page returns [this page](https://fylkestrafikk.no/menu/tickets-and-fares/how-to-buy-a-ticket-on-buses-and-express-boats/customer-service-centres-and-sales-outlets/). Clicking on the + sign left of *Do you want to buy tickets, buy or top up travelcards?* will reveal a list of places in Tromsø where you can buy tickets.

- WiTo Storgata
- Visit Tromsø, havneterminalen
- Narvesen Nerstranda
- Narvesen K1
- Senterinformasjon Jekta (v/gavekort)
- Narvesen UNN
- Mix Uit
- Narvesen Kroken
- Hurtigbåtterminalen på Finnsnes
- Billettautomater – lenke til hvor de er
- [Troms fylkestrafikks web shop](https://fylkestrafikk.no/menu/tickets-and-fares/web-shop/)
- Troms fylkestrafikks customer service center

Links to Google Maps can be found [here](https://fylkestrafikk.no/menu/help-and-contact/contact-us/opening-hours/)